# How to communicate from button click on parent to child components using angular2?

Tags: angular

I have a parent AppComponent and another component called "ChildComponent". Both of them share a service called "appState" that is injected into both (I am using https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter, the app.service.ts class is here https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.service.ts which is the appState I am referring to).

ChildComponent has its own property "mylist" that is an array of objects, set equal to this.appState.mylist.

```
@Component(...)
export class ChildComponent {
  mylist = any;
  constructor(@Inject(AppState) appState) {
    public appState = appState;
    mylist = appState.state.mylist;
  }
}
```

I have a template for ChildComponent that shows {{mylist}}

ParentComponent has a template that has a single "Add Me" button whose sole function is to add to this.appState.mylist.

My problem is, when I click on the "Add Me" button on the parent component, and within the function I log this.appState.mylist.

```
@Component(...)
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    public appState = appState;
    appState.mylist = [];
  }

  addMe() {
    this.appState.state.mylist.push({"itemName":"Something"});
    console.log(this.appState.mylist) // this outputs correctly and I see mylist growing
  }
}
```

I read about how eventEmitters can emit events to update the parent, but in my case, I want to update a component that is within the AppComponent template. What is wrong? How can I make it so that "mylist" in my child.component.html will show the right data?

All of the documentation I've seen appears to talk about EventEmitters which communicate from child to parent, which does not appear to work for me since I am trying to communicate from my parent AppComponent to child ChildComponent.

Issue plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/xaE905r4xNZcVJzWQwsr?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
The way OP has his service setup, the problem is child component wasn't getting the updated `appState.mylist`. So, the solution I am offering is to use `Subject` and `Observable` to notify the child component of changes and pull in new data via `subscription.`

child.components.ts:

```
mylist: any;

constructor(private appState: AppState){
  this.appState.dataString$.subscribe(
    data => {
      this.mylist = data.mylist; 
    });
}
```

Please see the [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JncNuE63jwQsYgImK2ba?p=info) for `service.ts` code.

**Original Post:**

Since you have parent-child relation you can pass `mylist` to child component as easily as just using data binding. 
`<child-component [mylist]="mylist"></child-component>`

In child component, you can use `@Input()` to bind the passed data from parent to `mylist` variable in child component.

If you still want to use shared service, then you are on right track, just need to clean up the code in parent and child components, which can look like following:

parent:

```
constructor(private appState: AppState){
    this.appState.mylist = [];
  }

  addMe() {
    this.appState.mylist.push({"itemName":"Something"});

    console.log(this.appState.mylist) // this outputs correctly and I see mylist growing

    this.mylistFromParent.push({"itemName":"Something"}); 
  }
```

child:

```
mylist: any;

  constructor(private appState: AppState){
  this.mylist = this.appState.mylist;
}
```

I have created this [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RwNbVAuYpg90Wyazutei?p=preview) illustrating both cases.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps! But can you try using the appService implementation that I referenced in my link? When I do the method I described, it locks up the whole interface and crashes.

Comment: method you describe with the shared service*

Comment: I did use `appState` (appService) for shared service, it called `AppState`, just like in your code. Only difference is the file name, in my demo its called `shared.service.ts`, which is most probably in your project named `app.service.ts`. 

Regarding the "locks up the whole interface and crashes", if you can share your code, that would be helpful :)

Comment: Created plunkr that shows the problem I am having off of your plunkr. I copied the "app.service.ts" referenced in my post to replace the contents of your shared.service.ts. Notice how its not working when I try to hit the add button. If you comment out the lines that use the appState, then the 2nd method works. https://plnkr.co/edit/xaE905r4xNZcVJzWQwsr?p=preview. I would prefer to get the first method working if this is at all possible. Please take a look and let me know what is going on.

Comment: There was a spelling mistake of `myListCopy` in the plunkr, that put me on a complete wrong track for a while. But I found the issue which is once the components instantiate to `AppState`, they don't get the updates. So, in the process of fixing it, I learned something new, using `Subject` and `observable` to notify all components of changes from shared service. I have marked the new lines clearly so that its easy for you to find them. Here's the plunkr link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/JncNuE63jwQsYgImK2ba

Comment: Very helpful, Master Nehal... If I have multiple components that are "subscribing" do I have to cleanup using ngDestroy or is this handled automatically?

Comment: AFAIK, if you use the `async` pipe, it's taken care of automatically, if not, then better to unsubscribe inside `ngDestroy`, just to ensure there are no memory leaks :)

Comment: Master Nehal knows best. Thank you!